# Error: Cannot display response in Dialogflow simulator. Please test on the Google Assistant simulator instead

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am using dialog flow to create an agent. When I try to embed it in my website, it gives me following error, "Cannot display response in Dialogflow simulator. Please test on the Google Assistant simulator instead.". It works perfectly fine in Google Assistant Simulator. I have seen people embed in their websites, but I don't know what I did different.

Any help would be appreciated.[Code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc20K.png) [Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJecZ.png) [Code3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEZZY.png) [Code4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7zAg.png)

The expected output is a conversation between user and agent.[Screenshot of my web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugxta.png) [Screenshot of Dialog Flow Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RBH6.png)

Comment: Can you edit your questions with code or the response that you set in dialogflow? Its hard to see what is going wrong without that.

Comment: Jordi, please check the screenshots that I have added.

Comment: Are you using any code or are you just using the Dialogflow UI for your intent responses?

Comment: I'll run you through the code. First the agent will ask for permission to use their name. Next, it will ask for their favorite color and return back a lucky number(length of the color string), irrespective where or not they give permission for using their name. Alas, it will ask them if they want to know a few fake color and end. I deployed the code through my ssh.

Comment: What I want to do is to embed this dialogflow action into my website(See the screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, judging by the screenshots you added, you are trying to send a Google Assistant specific response to Dialogflow. In your welcome intent you are returning an Permissions object. This is something that only works for the Google Assistant. The web demo that you are trying to embed into your website doesn't support Google Assistant specific objects.

If you want to use the webdemo try sending only texts messages back to your user by using `conv.ask("Your response")` and `conv.close("Your response")` or give a response specific for Dialogflow. You can do this by either checking the request in code and sending a different text only response for Dialogflow users or you can create a [Dialogflow only response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-responses#builtin) in the Dialogflow console. Dialogflow responses are refered to as Default on the console.

[image]

Comment: Thanks bud. I have another questions. What is the difference between deploying using firebase and using inline editor. I know it's lame. Neophyte. Hope you understand

Comment: There isn't much difference, Firebase hosts your backend code so you don't have to host your own server. The inline editor makes this even easier by allowing you to store a limited amount of code in the editor. When you deploy the code in the editor it uploads it to firebase for you. So basicly it's the same, but the inline editor does the work for you.

Comment: I want to make a dialogflow agent and integrate it in my website. The bot should take a color from me and return the length of color string. You have any samples that can help me.

Comment: Using firebase itself does not stop me from integrating into my website and just the google assistant specific object are the bottlenecks right?

Comment: Yeah, dialogflow doesnt care where you host your code, aslong as you provide your response in the correct format. Sending the google specific object breaks the expected format by Dialogflow